How to move C definition in an Arduino Sketch
I'm a Java developer, writing C in Arduino. My C skills are rusty. The code posted below, for an ESP8266, works fine in its current form, but I need to move the Pushsafer pushsafer(pushsaferKey, wifiClient); definition to the loop() function. In its current form, the pushsaferKey is in a define statement. I want to read that from EEPROM (which I know how to do), rather than have it hardcoded. How would I move it?
Thanks!
  #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
  #include <WiFiClient.h>
  #include <Pushsafer.h>

  char ssid[] = "my_ssid";
  char password[] = "my_pwd"; 

  boolean notificationSent = false;

  #define pushsaferKey "my_pushsafer_key"  // REPLACE THIS
  //String pushsaferKey = "";              // WITH THIS

  WiFiClient wifiClient;
  Pushsafer pushsafer(pushsaferKey, wifiClient);  //<<< problem, how to move to loop()?

  void sendNotification() {

    // See https://www.pushsafer.com/en/pushapi

    struct PushSaferInput input;
    input.message = "This is a test message";
    input.title = "This is a Test Title";
    input.sound = "8";
    input.vibration = "1";
    input.icon = "1";
    input.iconcolor = "#FFCCCC";
    input.priority = "1";
    input.device = "a";
    input.url = "https://www.pushsafer.com";
    input.urlTitle = "Open Pushsafer.com";
    input.picture = "";
    input.picture2 = "";
    input.picture3 = "";
    input.time2live = "";
    input.retry = "";
    input.expire = "";
    input.confirm = "";
    input.answer = "";
    input.answeroptions = "";
    input.answerforce = "";

    Serial.println(pushsafer.sendEvent(input));
    Serial.println("Notification Sent");
  }

  void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);

    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
    WiFi.disconnect();
    delay(100);

    Serial.print("Connecting Wifi: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
      Serial.print(".");
      delay(500);
    }

    Serial.println("\nWiFi connected");
    Serial.print("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  }

  void loop() {
    //read pushsaferKey from EEPROM
  //  pushsaferKey = "pushsafer_key_from_eeprom";  
  //  Pushsafer pushsafer(pushsaferKey, wifiClient); //<<< move to here

    while(!notificationSent) {  
      sendNotification();  
      notificationSent = true;
    }
  }


What do you intend Pushsafer pushsafer(pushsaferKey, wifiClient); to do?  Right now it looks like it is half a function declaration and half a function call.

problem, how to move to loop()? just move it, what happens if you do?

In sendNotification(),  the call to pushsafer.sendEvent(input) fails due to pushsafer not declared in scope.

Will that key change all the time? Can you read it once in setup function and just reuse it in loop function?

Arduino is using C++, not C.

The pushsaferkey is read from an NFC tag, then stored in EEPROM. When user wants to change key, they edit their NFC tag, and rescan. I am not showing the EEPROM step, because, as I mentioned in the OP, I don't need help with that. I don't know why so many people are down voting. Doesn't make sense.

I wasn't thinking. The solution was simple. See code:
      #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
      #include <WiFiClient.h>
      #include <Pushsafer.h>

      char ssid[] = "my_ssid";
      char password[] = "my_pwd"; 

      boolean notificationSent = false;
      String pushsaferKey = "";
      WiFiClient wifiClient;

      void sendNotification(String pushsaferKey) {

        // See https://www.pushsafer.com/en/pushapi
        
        Pushsafer pushsafer(pushsaferKey, wifiClient);

        struct PushSaferInput input;
        input.message = "This is a test message";
        input.title = "This is a Test Title";
        input.sound = "8";
        input.vibration = "1";
        input.icon = "1";
        input.iconcolor = "#FFCCCC";
        input.priority = "1";
        input.device = "a";
        input.url = "https://www.pushsafer.com";
        input.urlTitle = "Open Pushsafer.com";
        input.picture = "";
        input.picture2 = "";
        input.picture3 = "";
        input.time2live = "";
        input.retry = "";
        input.expire = "";
        input.confirm = "";
        input.answer = "";
        input.answeroptions = "";
        input.answerforce = "";

        Serial.println(pushsafer.sendEvent(input));
        Serial.println("Notification Sent");
      }

      void setup() {
        Serial.begin(115200);

        WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
        WiFi.disconnect();
        delay(100);

        Serial.print("Connecting Wifi: ");
        Serial.println(ssid);
        WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

        while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
          Serial.print(".");
          delay(500);
        }

        Serial.println("\nWiFi connected");
        Serial.print("IP address: ");
        Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
      }

      void loop() {
        //read pushsaferKey from EEPROM
        pushsaferKey = "pushsafer_key_from_eeprom";

        while(!notificationSent) {  
          sendNotification(pushsaferKey);  
          notificationSent = true;
        }
      }


Where reading from EEPROM is ?

I'm not adding the EEPROM step because that wasn't purpose of my question. People needing the EEPROM step can find examples in other topics.
